# jQuery.ajax() just receives an error, however jQuery.post() works

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

Debated whether to put this on WordPress.SE or here; decided that since it's primarily a jQuery question I'd post it here with the note that it occurred during WordPress development for context.

Long story short, following a [guide](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/how-to-use-ajax-in-wordpress/) on how to use AJAX in WordPress to the letter—including pasting in the same code excerpts to see if they run—doesn't work on my dev server.  The designated PHP function is never executed, and the call just returns a 0 when I dump the response to a an output div.

I added an `error:` field to the AJAX call and that triggered, but other than revealing that there was an error, I couldn't figure out what was actually at issue.

**Here's a look at the AJAX call, as shown in the guide.**

```
jQuery.ajax({
     type : "post",
     dataType : "json",
     url : myAjax.ajaxurl,
     data : {action: "my_user_vote", post_id : post_id, nonce: nonce},
     success: function(response) {
        if(response.type == "success") {
           jQuery("#vote_counter").html(response.vote_count)
        }
        else {
           alert("Your vote could not be added")
        }
     }
  })
```

Remembering having had this problem before, I decided to review an old project from a year ago, and found the following workaround, which seems to do the same thing, but actually returns the proper response from the script.

**Functional workaround, does what is expected**

```
var ajaxurl = '<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php';
var data = {action: "my_user_vote", post_id : post_id, nonce: nonce};

// Handle any returned values
jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
    if(response.type == "success") {
       jQuery("#vote_counter").html(response.vote_count)
    }
    else {
       alert("Your vote could not be added")
    }
});
```

Ostensibly, it seems that the latter is just a longwinded way of executing the former, but for some reason only the latter works.  **What could be causing the error on the first block?**

---

**EDIT:** It seems this may be a WordPress problem after all.  I've already sent the code I was working on the other night to production, so to reproduce it I put it into a plugin and tried to run it on the default theme.  It's working on the front end, but it's not working when I take it to a back-end page (which is what I was working on at the time).  According to the console, it appears to be an issue with enqueueing the scripts on the back end.

To mitigate that issue, I dumped the following on an otherwise blank back-end page:

```
    This post has <div id='vote_counter'>0</div> votes<br>
    <div id="output">Test</div>

    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready( function() {

            jQuery(".user_vote").click( function() {
                post_id = jQuery(this).attr("data-post_id")
                nonce = jQuery(this).attr("data-nonce")

                jQuery.ajax({
                    type : "post",
                    dataType : "json",
                    url : "<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
                    data : {action: "my_user_vote", post_id : post_id, nonce: nonce},
                    success: function(response) {
                        jQuery("#output").html(response)
                        jQuery("#vote_counter").html(5)
                    },
                    error: function(response) {
                        jQuery("#output").html(response)
                        jQuery("#vote_counter").html(10)}
                })

            })

        })
    </script>
        <?php
    $link = admin_url('admin-ajax.php?action=my_user_vote');
    echo '<a class="user_vote" href="' . $link . '">vote for this article</a>';
```

Long story short: There is no longer any external script to enqueue, the link is coded directly into it, and the count should update to 5 on success or 10 on failure (since this is a back-end page and therefore there's no page_id to check for).  All extraneous data fields have been dropped, since they won't be used in this form.

To simplify generating the response, I trimmed the code back to just the following:

```
function my_user_vote() {
    $result = array(
        'status' => 'success',
        'count' => 5
    );

    $result = json_encode($result);
    echo $result;

    die();
}
```

What now happens is we get redirected to a blank page with the JSON response dumped on it.  Tried dropping in the .post() method from above and that's doing the same thing for some reason.

**TL;DR:** This probably needs a move to wp.se.

Comment: You'll need to find out what the actual error is. Look in your browser's *Network* console and find the failing request, then look at the response details.

Comment: Just to confirm, `myAjax.ajaxurl` in the former gives the same string as `ajaxurl` in the latter doesn't it?

Comment: @Roamer-1888 Correct.  The former method uses WordPress's script localization functions to set the value, whereas the latter method just sets it directly prior to making the call.

Comment: Actually, it looks like you can use myAjax.ajaxurl as long as you've registered the script per the docs `wp_localize_script( 'my_voter_script', 'myAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ))); `

Comment: Not sure why you think the *latter* is long-winded. It's objectively shorter than the `jQuery.ajax` method

Comment: @Phil Noted, although it's not quite as clean with the pieces strewn about.  Really, it's just bugging me that such a well-documented method isn't working properly.

Comment: If the urls are the same then the only apparent difference is the explicit dataType in (1).
Try commenting out `dataType : "json",`. In its absence , jQuery will make a best guess, as it does in (2).

Comment: Just did some more testing trying to recreate the problem, since I can't go back to where the code was when I was working on this issue.  Findings documented in the edit above.

Comment: Kaji, FYI, signature of jQuery.ajax's error function is `(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)`. So to get a better idea of the error you would write, `jQuery("#output").html(textStatus || errorThrown)`.